# Как поменять номер индексов элементов массива c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string arr[8] = { "Math_Faculty" , "History_Faculty" , "Physic_Faculty" ,  "Math_Faculty" , "Philology_Faculty" , "Alogoritms" , "Philology_Faculty" , "Math_Faculty"};
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for(int j  = i ; j < 8; j++){
        if(i != j){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                arr[j] должен стать последним а остальные сменить индекс на один вниз
                Например когда попадаются две математики arr[0] и arr[3]  то arr[3] становится arr[7]
                А arr[4] становится arr[3] и т.д.
                Но когда arr[3] попадает в конец, для j должен продолжатся цикл а потом уже arr[4] становится arr[3]...
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string arr[8] = { "Math_Faculty" , "History_Faculty" , "Physic_Faculty" ,  "Math_Faculty" , "Philology_Faculty" , "Alogoritms" , "Philology_Faculty" , "Math_Faculty"};

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for(int j  = i ; j < 8; j++){
        if(i != j){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                std::string lastWord = arr[j]; // запомнили элемент, который нужно переместить

                // в цикле переставляем остальные элементы на один индекс вниз
                for(int k = j; k < 7; k++) {
                    arr[k] = arr[k+1];
                }

                arr[7] = lastWord; // вставляем последний элемент
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю, что Вы желаете получить в конечном результате

Каждый раз циклы будут отрабатывать n-1 раз. То есть, 7+6+5+4+3+2+1= 28 перестановок

> Element 0: 1
>   Element 1: 2
>   Element 2: 3
>   Element 3: 4
>   Element 4: 5
>   Element 5: 6
>   Element 6: 7
>   Element 7: 0

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 3
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 5
Element 4: 6
Element 5: 7
Element 6: 0
Element 7: 2

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 3
Element 2: 5
Element 3: 6
Element 4: 7
Element 5: 0
Element 6: 2
Element 7: 4

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 3
Element 2: 5
Element 3: 7
Element 4: 0
Element 5: 2
Element 6: 4
Element 7: 6

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 3
Element 2: 5
Element 3: 7
Element 4: 2
Element 5: 4
Element 6: 6
Element 7: 0

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 3
Element 2: 5
Element 3: 7
Element 4: 2
Element 5: 6
Element 6: 0
Element 7: 4

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 3
Element 2: 5
Element 3: 7
Element 4: 2
Element 5: 6
Element 6: 4
Element 7: 0

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 7
Element 3: 2
Element 4: 6
Element 5: 4
Element 6: 0
Element 7: 3

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 2
Element 3: 6
Element 4: 4
Element 5: 0
Element 6: 3
Element 7: 7

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 2
Element 3: 4
Element 4: 0
Element 5: 3
Element 6: 7
Element 7: 6

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 2
Element 3: 4
Element 4: 3
Element 5: 7
Element 6: 6
Element 7: 0

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 2
Element 3: 4
Element 4: 3
Element 5: 6
Element 6: 0
Element 7: 7

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 2
Element 3: 4
Element 4: 3
Element 5: 6
Element 6: 7
Element 7: 0

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 3
Element 4: 6
Element 5: 7
Element 6: 0
Element 7: 2

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 6
Element 4: 7
Element 5: 0
Element 6: 2
Element 7: 3

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 6
Element 4: 0
Element 5: 2
Element 6: 3
Element 7: 7

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 6
Element 4: 0
Element 5: 3
Element 6: 7
Element 7: 2

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 6
Element 4: 0
Element 5: 3
Element 6: 2
Element 7: 7

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 0
Element 4: 3
Element 5: 2
Element 6: 7
Element 7: 6

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 0
Element 4: 2
Element 5: 7
Element 6: 6
Element 7: 3

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 0
Element 4: 2
Element 5: 6
Element 6: 3
Element 7: 7

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 0
Element 4: 2
Element 5: 6
Element 6: 7
Element 7: 3

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 0
Element 4: 6
Element 5: 7
Element 6: 3
Element 7: 2

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 0
Element 4: 6
Element 5: 3
Element 6: 2
Element 7: 7

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 0
Element 4: 6
Element 5: 3
Element 6: 7
Element 7: 2

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 0
Element 4: 6
Element 5: 7
Element 6: 2
Element 7: 3

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 0
Element 4: 6
Element 5: 7
Element 6: 3
Element 7: 2

Element 0: 1
Element 1: 5
Element 2: 4
Element 3: 0
Element 4: 6
Element 5: 7
Element 6: 2
Element 7: 3

```
string arr[8] = {"0", "1" , "2" , "3" ,  "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" };


for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{

        for (int j = i; j < 7; j++) {

            string temp = arr[j];
            for (int k = j; k < 7; k++)
            {
                arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
            }
            arr[7] = temp;
            for (int a = 0; a <= 7; a++)
            {
                cout << "Element " << a << ": " << arr[a] << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;

        }
}
```